# Sketch - Exported files hidden?

Tags: sketch-app

When exporting images from Sketch, at least one of the images that is exported is hidden when viewing the folder it is exported to. Additionally, the image also cannot be overwritten if it has been exported and is now hidden. Is there a known cause for this?